# Sufficient Condition for the Existence of a Midpoint of a Chord

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

We have an arbitrary metric space $X$ for which there exists a subset $A \subseteq X$ satisfying $A' \neq\varnothing$ (the set of limit points of $A$).  **What do we need to assume about $X$ in order for the following to be true:**
$$
    \forall a,b \in X \hspace{1mm} \exists c\in X \colon d_X(a,c) = d_X(b,c)
$$
where $d_X$ denotes the metric of $X$?

Certainly, this is not true for *any* metric space. Take, for a counterexample,
$X=[0,10] \setminus\{5\}$ (endowed with the absolute value function), $a=2$, and $b=8$.

For context: I'm an undergrad who has never taken a course on topology.

Edit 1: Although it now appears to be a red herring, my original guess was connectedness.

Edit 2:
I am working on a problem (of which this is part) where I have *already* assumed the following about the metric $d_X$ of $X$:
$$
d_X(x,y) d_X(z,0) = d_X(zx, zy)
$$
$$
d_X(x,y) = d_X(x -y , 0)
$$
$$
d_X(x + y , 0) \leq
    d_X(x,0) + d_X(y,0)
$$
for any $x,y,z\in X$. Granted, this is somewhat coincidental, and the original question can be seen in a broader context. What originally motivated the question is my desire (in a proof I'm working on) to consider a neighborhood $N$ in $X$ which satisfies $a,b \in \partial(N)$. For concreteness, it oringinally seemed easiest to do so by considering a neighborhood $N_{d_X(c,a)}^X(c)$ where $c$ satisfies $d_X(a,c) = d_X(b,c)$. However, this requires that such a $c$ exists; hence, the original question.

Thank you.

Comment: $[0,10]\setminus\{5\}$ isn't connected.  cl$([0,5))=[0,5)$ in this space.

Comment: Wait, 5 isn't a limit point of $[0,5)$? For any $r>0$, w have $N_r(5) \cap [0,5) \setminus\{5\} = (5-r,5+r) \cap [0,5) \setminus\{5\} =(5-r,5) \neq\varnothing$. That this is non-empty can be seen by the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (to be fair, I didn't specify that $[0,10]\setminus\{5\} \subseteq \mathbb{R},$ but this was meant to be understood), so that cl$([0,5))=[0,5]$, no?

Comment: $5$ is certainly a limit point of $[0,5)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, but not in the space  $[0,10]\setminus\{5\}.$  The closure of $[0,5)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is not the same as the closure of $[0,5)$ in $[0,10]\setminus\{5\}.$  An equivalent way of saying that a space is not connected is that it is not the union of two disjoint open sets.  (This is the definition you are thinking of in the last line of your question, but you left out "open", or equivalently, "closed".)  These sets are open (or closed) in the space itself, not some ambient space.  >>

Comment: << Connectedness is a property of a topological space, considered by itself, not as a subspace of some other space.  This is a good question, by the way.  I don't know the answer, but it's a long time since I did any topology, so that doesn't mean much.

Comment: Ok I'll have to look into that definition of connectedness because, while I believe you, it's not 100% obvious to me why these definitions are equivalent. Thank you, by the way, this question is part of a feeble (but fun and instructive) attempt of mine to generalize Rolle's theorem to spaces besider $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: More to the point, I'm afraid it's still not clear to my why 5 is not a limit point of this $X$. Expanding the definition of a neighborhood, we have $N_r(5) :=\{x\in X : d_X(5,x) <r\}$, is that not right? So, technically, wouldn't it be that $N_r(5) \cap [0,5) \setminus\{5\} = (\max\{0,5-r\}, \min\{10,5-r\}  \cap [0,5) \setminus\{5\}$ which is still non-empty?

Comment: Connectedness isn't necessary.  The rational provide an example.

Comment: It's simply that $5$ is not in the space.  Limit points have to belong to the space.

Comment: Yeah, I see... thank you that was what I didn't realize.

Comment: In the discrete metric, all points other than $a$ and $b$ itself fulfil that property, therefore any discrete metric space with at least three points qualified. For reference, in the discrete metric, two different points always have the distance $1$.

Comment: I note that your title mentions "chord"s, but your predicate for the midpoint does not require the existence of more than three points.  Did you intend to require the existence of a chord?

Comment: Hm I like that, @celtschk, coincidentally I briefly considered that in the context of a different problem a minute ago. However, a metric space with this metric cannot have any limit points (I think, is that right?), which would be unfortunate for the problem I'm trying to apply this to.  So, I wonder if this can avoided...

Comment: @EricTowers haha I'm sure that I'm abusing the term in the interest of a poetic titile. TBC, the question is *not* intended to specifically refer to mid points of a line between two points on a circle in Euclidean 2-space (which, I think, is the actual definition of a chord, or close to it). The intent is what is stated in the body of the question. Does that seem fair? Because, I mean, I could change the title if it is misleading

Comment: It only can be avoided by adding more conditions that exclude metrics without limit points. For the actual midpoint of a chord in Euclidean space, the additional condition $d_X(a,b)=d_X(a,c)+d_X(c,b)$ holds (in Euclidean space, this essentially says that $c$ is in between $a$ and $b$). This would exclude the discrete metric, and I think it would ensure that any point can be a limit point. So maybe that additional condition is suitable for your purpose.

Comment: Huh, I actually didn't know that about a midpoint of a chord @celtschk. I'll continue to think about it. In the meantime, you've motivated me to narrow the parameters of the question (I don't know if people on this website will like or dislike that...).

Comment: So from your edit, I get you don't have just any metric space, but at least a ring-like structure (from the given formulas, one cannot derive whether all ring laws hold in $X$, obviously).

Comment: BTW, your last inequality isn't really a new condition, but a consequence of the equation before that and the triangle inequality: $d(x+y,0) = d(x,-y) \le d(x,0) + d(0,-y) = d(x,0)+d(y,0)$.

Comment: Yes, in fact a field by assumption, although I didn't occur to me that this might affect the answer. Also, yeah... huh thank you for pointing that out about the last condition, I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been Googling, but I can't find anything directly related to your question.  [This paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1975-047-02/S0002-9939-1975-0355791-0/S0002-9939-1975-0355791-0.pdf) is the closest thing I've found. It's concerned with the Euclidean plane, but the very beginning treats an arbitrary metric space.

Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of a metric space $(X,d)$ and let $x\in X.$  Define the distance from $x$ to $A$ by $$D(x,A) = \inf\{d(x,a)|a\in A\}.$$  Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty subsets of a metric space $X.$  Define the equisdant set determined by $A$ and $B$ as $$\{A=B\}=\{x\in X| d(x,A)=d(x,B) \}$$

In your question, $A$ and $B$ are singleton sets.

In the paper it is shown that

> **Theorem $\mathbf{1}$** The metric space $X$ is connected if and only if equidistant sets in $X$ are never void.

In $\mathbb{Q}$, $\{A=B\}\neq\emptyset$ when $A$ and $B$ are singleton sets, but if we take $$A=\{x\in\mathbb{q}|x>\sqrt{2}\}\\
B=\{x\in\mathbb{q}|x<\sqrt{2}\}$$ then clearly, $$\{A=B\}=\emptyset.$$

Comment: I'll mentally double check quickly, but I think that actually answers my question! Thank you. True, your example demonstrates that the assumption that $X$ is connected is more than sufficient, however I don't find that to be an unreasonably strong assumption in the context of what I'm working on (since Rolle's theorem is typically stated in terms of intervals of real numbers, which are connected).

Comment: Thank you sharing that paper, by the way; there's a lot of useful stuff in there. Also, if you're interested in refining the discussion of this question, I can leave it unanswered for the moment and/or restate the question so that it asks for the least restrictive sufficient condition which gives the desired result. If you don't have an opinion on the matter, that's fine too

Answer (score 1):

Your additional conditions, mentioned in the edit, together with the condition from the comments that $X$ is actually a field, are *almost* sufficient for the existence of a point with equal distance. The only other thing we have to add is that the field is *not* of characteristic $2$ (that is, in that field $1+1\ne 0$).

To see this, first note that $d_X(x,0) = d_X(0,x) = d_X(-x,0)$ (the first by symmetry of the metric, the second by your second restriction, which BTW just says the metric is translation invariant).

Now define $c=\frac{a+b}{2}$; since $2\ne 0$, this element exists by the field axioms. Then we have
\begin{align}
d_X(a,c) &= d_X(a-c,0) && \text{(translation invariance)}\\
&= d_X(\frac{a-b}{2},0) && \text{(inserting $c$ and simplifying)}\\
&= d_X(\frac{b-a}{2},0) && \text{(the relation above)}\\
&= d_X(b-c,0) && \text{(using the definition of $c$ again)}\\
&= d_X(b,c) && \text{(translation invariance)}
\end{align}

Comment: The more time I spend with this and related problems, the more I grow to appreciate your answer. It's quite ingenious actually. I don't think I could have come up with it.